# Get XML element declaration from imported ("xsd:import") schema in a WSDL file by using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, wsdl, xsd

I have a problem that's been getting into my nerves for a week.

I programmed a dummy web service as a stateless EJB using Netbeans 7.2.1:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "WSPersonLookup")
@Stateless()
public class WSPersonData {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="PUWSPersonData")
  private EntityManager em;

 /**
  * Web service operation
  */
  @WebMethod(operationName = "getPersonData")
  public Person getPersonData(@WebParam(name = "personId") final String personId) {
    return em.find(Person.class, personId);
  }
}
```

The class "Person" is just a JPA Entity mapped to this table (I used PostgreSQL as DBMS):

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  id character varying(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  nit text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  name text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  address text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  phone integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  creation_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The resulting WSDL is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.i2b.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.i2b.com/" name="WSPersonLookup">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.i2b.com/" schemaLocation="http://pc-i2b:8080/WSPersonLookup/WSPersonData?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="getPersonData">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getPersonData" />
  </message>
  <message name="getPersonDataResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getPersonDataResponse" />
  </message>
  <portType name="WSPersonData">
    <operation name="getPersonData">
      <input wsam:Action="http://ws.i2b.com/WSPersonData/getPersonDataRequest" message="tns:getPersonData" />
      <output wsam:Action="http://ws.i2b.com/WSPersonData/getPersonDataResponse" message="tns:getPersonDataResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="WSPersonDataPortBinding" type="tns:WSPersonData">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
    <operation name="getPersonData">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="WSPersonLookup">
    <port name="WSPersonDataPort" binding="tns:WSPersonDataPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://pc-i2b:8080/WSPersonLookup/WSPersonData" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

XSD declarations:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://ws.i2b.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://ws.i2b.com/">
  <xs:element name="getPersonData" type="tns:getPersonData"/>
  <xs:element name="getPersonDataResponse" type="tns:getPersonDataResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="person" type="tns:person"/>
  <xs:complexType name="getPersonData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="personId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="getPersonDataResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="tns:person" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="creationDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="nit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem is: I need to access the schema declarations above, imported in the WSDL:

```
 <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.i2b.com/" schemaLocation="http://pc-i2b:8080/WSPersonLookup/WSPersonData?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
```

by using XPath. I'm not allowed to access the schema directly.

Is there a way to do that? If not, does anyone know a workaround for this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fetch a secondary XML document (the schema in this case) referenced by a primary XML document (the WSDL) using just XPaths.

Using XSLT you can do it with the `document()` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="schema" select="document(/soap:definitions/soap:types/xsd:schema/xsd:import/@schemaLocation)"/>
```

Alternatively, instead than trying to fetch the imported schema, just get the schema fragment inside the WSDL - using an XPath like `/soap:definitions/soap:types/xsd:schema`. This IS a valid schema, importing the one at `http://pc-i2b:8080/WSPersonLookup/WSPersonData?xsd=1` - and you should be able to use it directly.